# java.lang.ClassCastException for <include> tag using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have the following setup. `main` module depends on `search` module which depends on `commonui` module. All three modules are using data binding. Inside `commonui` module I have `toolbar.xml` file. This file is used inside `search` module in `fragment.xml` file using `<include>` tag like this:

```
<include
     android:id="@+id/fem_toolbar"
     layout="@layout/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

After running the app, when navigating to fragment with this xml I get following crash:

```
E/CrashLogHandler: Stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xx.xxxxx.debug/xx.xxxxx.search.Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: xx.xxxxx.databinding.ToolbarBindingImpl cannot be cast to xx.xxxxx.common.ui.databinding.ToolbarBinding
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Does anybody have an idea what is happening?
I have also seen a similar issue with this library: https://github.com/heinrichreimer/material-intro/issues/256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong with my setup.
I was moving search related parts of the app into `search` module. I moved everything except the definition of `SearchActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
So for some reason, data binding behaves weird when activity is defined like this.
Simply moving definition of activity do `search` module's `AndroidManifest.xml` solved the issue.